# Flip shapes in Keynote presentations over 45degree axes

Tags: macos, keynote, animation

How can I flip a rhombus over one of its sides? I can make it by magic tool but is there another way to do it?

[image]

Comment: When you say flip, are you rotating it in place or more interested in the move across the axis you defined?

Comment: as it shown in the image by the flash but not rotation flipping over one of it's sides